# How to delete sequence of rows with same value with a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have the following dataframe:

| . | id | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | no |
| 1 | 3 | no |
| 2 | 3 | no |
| 3 | 3 | yes |
| 4 | 3 | no |
| 5 | 5 | no |
| 6 | 5 | no |
| 7 | 5 | yes |
| 8 | 5 | yes |
| 9 | 6 | no |
| 10 | 6 | no |
| 11 | 6 | yes |
| 12 | 6 | yes |
| 13 | 6 | yes |
| 14 | 6 | yes |
| 15 | 6 | yes |
| 16 | 6 | no |
| 17 | 6 | no |

I would like to delete all rows of 'yes' if they are the last 'yes' in the outcome column.

I would also like to drop all 'no' if they are the first values in the dataframe

These must be grouped by the 'id' column
This should be the output:

| . | id | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | yes |
| 4 | 3 | no |
| 11 | 6 | yes |
| 12 | 6 | yes |
| 13 | 6 | yes |
| 14 | 6 | yes |
| 15 | 6 | yes |
| 16 | 6 | no |
| 17 | 6 | no |

At the moment I have tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
       'id': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 
       'outcome': ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no']
     })

m1 = df.groupby(['id'])['outcome'].head() != 'yes'
df = df.drop(m1[m1].index)
m2 = df.groupby(['id'])['outcome'].tail() != 'no'
df = df.drop(m2[m2].index)

print(df)
```

If I put a 1 in `head()` and `tail()` , this just removes the last value and not the preceding values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute masks and slice.
In summary, I computed here the rank of each stretch of yes/no to determine if they are initial (= rank 1) of final (=max rank per group).

```
o = df['outcome']
g = df.groupby('id')['outcome']
m1 = o.ne(g.shift()).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
m2 = m1.groupby(df['id']).transform('max')
df[~((m1.eq(1)&o.eq('no'))|(m1.eq(m2)&o.eq('yes')))]
```

Output:

```
    id outcome
3    3     yes
4    3      no
11   6     yes
12   6     yes
13   6     yes
14   6     yes
15   6     yes
16   6      no
17   6      no
```

*NB. The final mask used in slicing could be simplified using boolean arithmetics, but I left it as is for clarity on the conditions*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details, so I re-ran this and It doesn't keep all the following 'no' values after the 'yes' outcomes. For example, there could be more than one 'no' after the 'yes'.

Comment: Can you provide an updated example?

Comment: yep, just added an extra row to the end of the table

Comment: @TSRAI I'm confused, when I run my code, this give the expected output (I updated the output based on your new df)

Comment: apologies, I checked on an updated df!